# Textbox returning a weird string when whitespace is last character

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I'm trying to read characters insert in a textbox, however I'm finding it difficult because if my last character is a whitespace (the string must be read "as is", it's a requirement), the textbox Text property returns something like "     \r\n" (yea with like 8 whitespaces).

Any suggestion on how to avoid this? I need to read that last whitespace, not remove it, but I don't want that weird thing.

Thanks for any answer.

**Edit 1:**

**xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="GSdk.SkypePlugin.ConfigureWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="GSdk.SkypePlugin configuration" Height="308" Width="486" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" Topmost="True">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,54,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="How much time should be displayed the plugin as a foreground applet for each word (seconds):" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="375" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Should the applet be displayed over everything when a message is received:" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,32,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="(care with this option, if SkypePlugin has focus, it will lose it)" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <CheckBox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="401,32,0,0" Name="showWhenMessageIncomingCheckbox" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Slider Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,91,0,0" Name="SecondsPerWordSlider" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="375" Minimum="1" Value="1" AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight" AutoToolTipPrecision="1" LargeChange="0.1" SmallChange="0.01" />
        <Button Content="Save" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="389,246,0,0" Name="saveButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="saveButton_Click" />
        <Button Content="Cancel" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="305,246,0,0" Name="cancelButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="cancelButton_Click" />
        <Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="420,86,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="32" Content="{Binding ElementName=SecondsPerWordSlider, Path=Value}" />
        <TextBox xml:space="preserve" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,129,170,0" Name="m_MessageSeparatorTextbox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=m_UseMessageSeparator, Path=IsChecked}" Text=" " />
        <CheckBox Content="Use message separator:" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,132,0,0" Name="m_UseMessageSeparator" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**cs file**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace GSdk.SkypePlugin
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logica di interazione per ConfigureWindowxaml.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ConfigureWindow : Window
    {
        public ConfigureWindow(double secondsPerWord = 1.0, bool showWhenMessageIncoming = true, bool useMessageSeparator = true, string messageSeparator = " ")
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Icon = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(Properties.Resources.LCDMedia_SkypePluginAppIcon.ToBitmap().GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            SecondsPerWordSlider.Value = secondsPerWord;
            showWhenMessageIncomingCheckbox.IsChecked = showWhenMessageIncoming;
            m_UseMessageSeparator.IsChecked = useMessageSeparator;
            m_MessageSeparatorTextbox.Text = messageSeparator;
        }

        private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void saveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = true;
        }

        public bool ShowWhenMessageIncoming { get { return (showWhenMessageIncomingCheckbox.IsChecked.HasValue ? showWhenMessageIncomingCheckbox.IsChecked.Value : false); } }
        public double SecondsPerWord { get { return SecondsPerWordSlider.Value; } }
        public string MessageSeparator { get { return m_MessageSeparatorTextbox.IsEnabled ? m_MessageSeparatorTextbox.Text : " "; } }
        public bool UseMessageSeparator { get { return m_UseMessageSeparator.IsChecked.HasValue ? m_UseMessageSeparator.IsChecked.Value : true; } }
    }
}
```

**calling code**

```
    private void AppletConfigureHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<SkypeApplet>(a =>
        {
            bool restart = false;
            lock (a.SyncRoot)
            {
                var w = new ConfigureWindow(Properties.Settings.Default.SecondsPerWord, Properties.Settings.Default.ShowWhenMessageIncoming, Properties.Settings.Default.UseMessageSeparator, Properties.Settings.Default.MessageSeparator);
                var result = w.ShowDialog();
                if (result.HasValue && result.Value == true)
                {
                    Properties.Settings.Default.SecondsPerWord = w.SecondsPerWord;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.ShowWhenMessageIncoming = w.ShowWhenMessageIncoming;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.MessageSeparator = w.MessageSeparator;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.UseMessageSeparator = w.UseMessageSeparator;
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    restart = true;
                }
            }
            if (restart)
                App.Restart();
        }), this);
    }
```

**Note:** I tested in this moment with xml:space, normally isn't there.

Comment: Can you provide a short but complete repro of this problem?

Comment: I just discovered I can't reproduce it in another project, I'm posting some code but the window is very simple. See my edit in a minute. The problem is quite easy to reproduce on my project, I insert only 1 space in the textbox and then press "save", with a breakpoint i can read something like this "      \r\n" instead of just a whitespace.

Comment: "\r\n" is a carriage return and newline, which is usually just a newline in your string. Do you add this somewhere?

Comment: What does `xml:space="preserve"` provide _you_?

Comment: No that's the problem. And it's not adding just \r\n, it's adding around 10 whitespaces **and** \r\n.

Comment: @jberger: Nothing, I'm removing it infact. It seems that the problem is not about the textbox but about saving the string in Settings.Default. Still, I don't add anything to that string in any place of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this, seems like I found the problem by myself and is very stupid.

Infact, I stored for some reason the "     \r\n" in the Settings string. After reloading it in my configuration window, it seems that I couldn't delete that string from my text in the textbox because my textbox is single line, while \r\n is on the second line.

I'm still not sure why I can't delete all those whitespaces, but I think this is the answer. If someone has a better one, I'll be glad to him/her.

Thanks.

**Edit 1:**
Seems that something screwed up between app.config and .settings file, I fixed it by edit both of them manually.

**Edit 2:** 
I found the problem: if I restart the application right after saving, I don't know why my string gets filled with those characters. I don't understand why this happens.